# Why does VSCode keep connecting to Apple?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a web debugger running on my machine, and I noticed that VSCode is running a lot of web calls to `captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html` followed by a call to `ipv4.icanhazip.com:443` every second. The body of the Apple call is `<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Success</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Success</BODY></HTML>`

What is VS Code up to in the background?

[image]

Comment: I'm 70% sure this is on topic, but if it isn't, feel free to move to the appropriate SE site.

Comment: Looks like it could be related to a router that requires "authentication" before being able to use data (often used in public wi-fi). See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7491051

Comment: But only when I'm running VS Code? Seems odd that an IDE cares, especially in a Windows environment, with no Apple devices.

Comment: The IDE has nothing to do with this. It is probably just trying to access the internet and the router is holding you "captive", causing the *system* to do that.

Comment: How are you connecting to the internet? Through hotspot on your phone? Public wifi?

Comment: @epascarello A generic office wifi network.

Comment: @crashmstr I have plenty of other applications talking to the internet over the same adapter and I don't see this behavior, only from the IDE.

Comment: Try disabling any installed extensions and/or a different network.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the Atlassian plugin. I'll go bug them about it I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had to do with the underlying online/offline detection library we were using in the Atlassian for VS Code extension. We have since removed the dependency and now only connect to Atlassian servers. We've also backed off the aggressiveness of the checks.